# Datestamp trigger for pgAdmin written in C

Tags: c, postgresql, triggers, pgadmin

We have postgres 8 installed on a linux box, and I'm copying over data and triggers from our windows version to this new one.  However, plpgsql isn't installed by default, so copying my trigger source is failing. I only have C or Internal languages to choose from; barring asking the DBA to install plpgsql, can anyone help me convert this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "datestampTrigger"()

RETURNS "trigger" AS
'BEGIN
-- check for datecreated
IF NEW.datecreated IS NULL THEN
    NEW.datecreated := ''now'';
END IF;
NEW.datelastmodified := ''now'';
RETURN NEW;
END;'
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: You have a need ask the DBA to install it and see what they say. Worry about a work around once a wall is put up that you need to work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most linux systems I have encountered plpgsql is actually installed on the system but is not included in the database template. Executing the following "activates" plpgsql in your database.

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You have to be superuser user to issue that command with success.

Comment: Yeah, so I have to let the dba do it anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: Database owners can do that to if plpgsql is a trusted language which it normally is.